# Javascript variable declare scope

Tags: javascript

Why `c variable` of if condition can work in global scope and `b variable` not work on global... ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    <!--
        var a = 45;
        function print(){
            var b = 10;
            document.write(a);
        }
        if(a == 45)
        {
            var c = 10;
        }
        print();
        document.write("a is : " + a + "<br />");
        document.write("b is : " + b + "<br />");
        document.write("c is : " + c + "<br />");
    //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why variable b is local

When **variable b** will always be created when execution context of **function print()** is created and will be destroyed once the function is completed. So it is dependent on that function, hence is local to that function.

> Why variable c is global

But in case of **var c** inside if condition, its execution context is created at the global level and **var c** is declared. It is just assigned a  value when that condition in 'if' becomes true.

You can read hoisting for more details: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: Thank you .... You mean C variable is auto create in global level with in execution... ?

Comment: Yes, thats correct, and the value to var c gets assigned if the 'if condition' is satisfied, but if you console.log the var c it will say undefined and not undeclared, that means it has been declared in the global context

Answer (score 1):

Because `b`  variable having block scope within `print` function, and `c` variable is declared outside the `print` function thats why `c` variable having global scope

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable in a function, it's only available in the function and it will disappear after the function is executed. Declaring a variable in a function makes it only accessible within the function; outer commands cannot access that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because b variable is initialized inside the function print.. and c variable is initialised on the global scope. 
so at this line:

```
document.write("b is : " + b + "<br />");
```

you trying to get the value of b variable but ur not calling the function print..

look at this :

```
var a = 45;
        var b;
        var c;
        function print(){
           b = 10;
            document.write(a);
        }
        if(a == 45)
        {
            var c = 10;
        }
        document.write("a is : " + a + "<br />");
        document.write("b is : " + b + "<br />");
        document.write("c is : " + c + "<br />");
    //-->
```

it will print the following:

```
 a is : 45
 b is : undefined
 c is : 10
```

because b didn`t change as the function has not yet been called .. but c has changed by the if statement which lies on the global scope.

```
var a = 45;
    var c;

    function print() {
      b = 10;
      document.write(a);
    }
    print()
    if (a == 45) {
      var c = 10;
    }
    document.write("a is : " + a + "<br />");
    document.write("b is : " + b + "<br />");
    document.write("c is : " + c + "<br />");
    //-->
```

Comment: Thank you...... Ohh it`s my wrong.... but I asked how can c variable work in global scope.... ?

Comment: c variable is on te scope already  as all if statements, its conditions and it is code ..all on te scope unless you move it inside a function.

Comment: i added some more info above.

Comment: or u can call the function and it will automatically add b to the scope.  but careful u still have to keep declaring b variable without the var keyword.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare **b** in global scope and make it 10 when condition is satisfied. In your code b is inside scope of the function hence it si not global

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    <!--
        var a = 45,b;
        function print(){
             b = 10;
            document.write(a);
        }
        if(a == 45)
        {
            var c = 10;
        }
        document.write("a is : " + a + "<br />");
        document.write("b is : " + b + "<br />");
        document.write("c is : " + c + "<br />");
    //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `a == 45` so `c = 10`, but `b` is scoped off in your `print` function. Note that you should avoid `document.write` and `print` is a property of `window` already, so you're overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

2 reasons why your code is failing.

#### 1. You are not calling print function

#### 2 You are using local variable in global scope.

Variable `b` is defined in function so it's local variable, and it's scope is in function it self. So you should declare `b` to global scope.

Try Initializing var b and removing `var` keyword from function

```
var a= 45, b = 0;
function print(){
b = 10; 
...
```

### [More detailed understanding of Variable Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When variable declared using `var` it does not belong to the scope of the statements, thus there is not a scope of the `if` and the `c` is declared globally.
But if you declare the variable in the function, it belongs to the nearest enclosing function's scope, so `b` cannot be a global one.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

> Variable declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any
>   code is executed. The scope of a variable declared with var is its
>   current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or,
>   for variables declared outside any function, global.